# How to hide simple products in Magento front end?

Tags: php, magento

I am inserting some products in magento programmatically, I want to show just configurable products in front end (Like magento itself) and when user selects "View Details" in details page he can select attributes to select the associated simple product.(I dont want to show associated products in front end)
But now both configurable and simple products are available in product list in front end. why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `General` tab of the simple products, set `Visibility` to `Not Visible Individually`. This will hide them from the front-end, but keep them enabled for use with the configurable products.

This can also be done programmatically if that's how you're creating the products:

```
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)

// from Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility:
// const VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE    = 1;
// const VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG     = 2;
// const VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH      = 3;
// const VISIBILITY_BOTH           = 4;

// remember to call $product->save() at some point
```

Comment: He stated he was doing it programitcally... so if you know the calls to make on the product(s) please give some example code and/or links to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks friends! I found it. I set visibility to Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH and now it's Ok

Comment: That's true. I've added example code for it. You might want to use `VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE` instead of `VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH` so that your customers don't land on the simple products through the search page. Depends on what your intentions are.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the simple products from frontend, you can also do this from backend, without writing any code.

Go to Catalog->Manage Products, in the Type dropdown, filter "simple product". After filtering select all products and select "Update Attributes" from Mass action. From there change the visibility to "Not Visible Individually" which will be applied to all simple products.

Comment: i found this more helpful than the accepted answer - many thanks

Comment: @Jimmery Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends! I found it. I set visibility to `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH` and now it's Ok